# Taking a heap dump on already crashed system

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-dump

My tomcat application crashed due to memory leak.
I want to take the heap dump on the crashed system/jvm.
Is it possible? I am using windows/tomcat 6
How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a heap dump on a process that is no longer running. Next time you start Tomcat, you're going to have to edit the file in the /bin directory called [`catalina.sh`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/bin/catalina.sh) first so that it contains options to automatically dump the heap if it runs out of memory.

What you need to do is to edit the `JAVA_OPTS` variable so that contains the JVM options you need. So near the top of the file, after `JAVA_OPTS` has been created, you need to do something like

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"`

You can also take heap dumps using JConsole, but in order to do this, you need to know roughly when Tomcat is running out of memory in order for the heap dump to help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The process does not exists anymore. So there is no heap to dump.
Use '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError' for the next time.

Comment: It means I need to wait till next crash :(

Comment: Yes, it does. There is no getting around that.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the heap dump at runtime by:

jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=heap.dump

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not responding but the JVM is still limping, you may try using JConsole and trigger a Heap Dump. Search for Heap Dump on this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)